# How to include multiple layers within the same dataframe using tmap in R?

Tags: r, gis, tmap

I am working with some public datasets, which can be [accessed here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tHsvGr_oJgrOL5X2bTlUS60sSg2CcXBq?usp=sharing) inside the 'stack_question' folder).

I am trying to create a map of all the supermarkets within the state of Kansas using the `tmap` library in `R`. Using `ggplot`, I generated a map using the following code:

```
library(pacman)
p_load(sf, tidyverse, tmap)

#Read in data
super <- readRDS('supermarket_pt.RDS')
ct<-st_read("US_tract_2010.shp")
food <- read_csv('FoodAtlas.csv')

#Reproject so datasets are projeted in the same way
super <- st_transform(super, st_crs(ct))

#Change data structure to 'numeric'
ct$GEOID10 <- as.numeric(ct$GEOID10)
food$CensusTract <- as.numeric(food$CensusTract)

#Selct for relevant columns to combine the dataset
food <- food %>% 
  select(CensusTract:County)

#Left join ct and modified food dataset
sup <- left_join(ct, food, by = c('GEOID10' = 'CensusTract'))

#Filter dataset to desired state
ks <- sup %>% 
  filter(State == "Kansas")

#Find the supermarkets in Kansas
super_ks <- super[ks, op = st_within]

#Plot the data
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = ks) +
  geom_sf(data = super_ks, color = 'steelblue', shape = 18, size = 2)
```

The following image is output, which is correct:

[image]

I need to make the same image with `tmap`. The problem is that I am getting an error when I run the following code:

```
#Set tmap mode
tmap_mode('plot')

#Spatially join data
super_state <- st_join(ks, super_ks, join = st_contains, left = TRUE)
na.omit(super_state)

#Generate KS map
qtm(super_state)+
  tm_bubbles('name', col = 'steelblue')
```

The error:

```
Error: size argument of tm_symbols/tm_dots is not a numeric variable
```

When I try this code, I get an image that produces what I don't want:

```
tm_shape(super_state) +
  tm_polygons('name')
```

[image]

How can I make my `tmap` map look like the first one?

Comment: The point of `tm_bubbles` is to do a bubble plot where the size of the dot corresponds to something in the data. You just want regular old dots, so use `tm_dots()`, maybe `qtm(super_state) + tm_dots(col = 'steelblue')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to replicate the map, but the file `FoodAtlas.csv` is missing. I think this should work (just using the same data that you used for `ggplot2` ):

```r
# Same with tmap, you don't need to  create new spatial objects
tm_shape(ks) +
  tm_polygons() +
  tm_shape(super_ks) +
  tm_dots("steelblue", shape = 18, size = 2)
```

You are getting the second map because you are using `name` on `col` parameter. `tmap` works a bit different than `ggplot2`:

- If you use `tm_polygons(col="<variable>")` you get a choropleth map. The equivalent in ggplot is `geom_sf(aes(fill=<variable>))`.
- If you use `tm_polygons(col="red" )` or the name of a color in general you get the shape with each polygon filled with that color (equivalent to `geom_sf(fill="<a color>")`.

So basically, on `ggplot2` you need to specifically declare the type of layer (using `aes` or not, depending on your map) but in `tmap` this is done depending of the type of variable. See here a full reprex:

```r
library(pacman)
p_load(sf, tidyverse, tmap, giscoR)


# Mock your data
ks <- gisco_get_nuts(country = "Belgium", nuts_level = 3)
super_ks <- gisco_get_healthcare(country = "Belgium")

super_ks <- st_transform(super_ks, st_crs(ks))


# Test1: Simple map, plot just the layers
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = ks) +
  geom_sf(data = super_ks, color = 'steelblue', shape = 18, size = 2)
```

[image]

```r
# Same with tmap
tm_shape(ks) +
  tm_polygons() +
  tm_shape(super_ks) +
  tm_dots("steelblue", shape = 18, size=.5)
```

[image]

```r
# Test 2: Using aes/col: Thematic map

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data=ks, aes(fill=NUTS_ID)) +
  geom_sf(data = super_ks, color = 'steelblue', shape = 18, size = 2)
```

[image]

```r
# Same with tmap
tm_shape(ks) +
  tm_polygons("NUTS_ID") +
  tm_shape(super_ks) +
  tm_dots("steelblue", shape = 18, size=.5)
```

[image]